# Mute phone notifications from Fallout Shelter

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-shelter

I decided to give Fallout Shelter a try. I'm really enjoying it. However, I do have a life, and I can't be at the beck and call of my mobile phone every five minutes.

The game sends notifications to my phone constantly when I'm not playing. During meetings, in the middle of the night... I get that stuff is happening in the game world, but I can't attend to it 24/7; I need to turn them off so it doesn't badger me constantly, or else just uninstall the game.

But I can't find how to turn them off!!! The game settings don't seem to have anything about it, and in my phone's notification settings, I can see all the other apps that have sent notifications, but not Fallout Shelter.

I can't turn my phone on DnD mode or switch off phone notifications entirely because I rely on some of the other notifications for important real-life stuff.

Can anyone help me out before I give up and delete the whole game?

The phone is an Android-based Samsung Galaxy S9, by the way, in case that helps.

Comment: Are you completely sure Fallout Shelter doesn’t appear on the notification panel at settings?

Comment: If you press and hold on a notification from the app does it change to become notification options? Should include toggles to disable some specific notifications (if any) along with all notifications. There may also be a notifications menu in game to change what you're notified about.

Comment: If you had an apple device, you could switch those important notifications you mentioned to the “important notifications” category and they would show up even if you have DnD mode activated. So that asks, is there a similar option on android?